# Fill a combobox in WPF with a list of web services

Tags: wpf, web-services, combobox

I have a control like this:

```
             <ComboBox x:Name="ComboTipo" 
              Height="23"   
              SelectionChanged="ComboTipo_SelectionChanged" 
              Width="450" 
              Canvas.Left="609" 
              Canvas.Top="26" />
```

And my code is:

```
        ComboTipo.DisplayMemberPath = "Descripcion";
        ComboTipo.SelectedValuePath = "IdTipoPersona";
        ComboTipo.ItemsSource = myWebServices.dameTipos();
```

My web services returns a list for this object, this class is created in automatic when i add the reference to the web services:

```
public partial class TipoPersona {

    private short idTipoPersonaField;

    private string descripcionField;

    /// <comentarios/>
    public short IdTipoPersona {
        get {
            return this.idTipoPersonaField;
        }
        set {
            this.idTipoPersonaField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    public string Descripcion {
        get {
            return this.descripcionField;
        }
        set {
            this.descripcionField = value;
        }
    }        
}
```

But the problem is:

The combobox displays the data types for each element of the list, and i want display the Descripcion.

Can you help me plis! Thanks

Comment: Sorry i don´t know how to edit this question but the name of the combobox is correctly

Answer (score 0):

What does IdTipoPersona look like? Is it a class you created? If so, you may need to reference the property that you want displayed. It would look something like this:

```
ComboTipoPersona.SelectedValuePath = "IdTipoPersona.Text";
```

Where *Text* would be replaced by the property. It is really hard to judge otherwise what is going on with knowing a little more about the object structure that *myWebServices.dameTipos()* returns.

**EDIT**

Ok I was able to simulate your problem and simulate a solution as well.
Your issue is in the Tipos class. There are a couple of things necessary when binding to a combobox with a custom class.

1. First off, you will want to add accessors and mutators (getters and setters) to IdTippoPersona and Descripcion.
2. You should add a constructor that assigns to those properties with parameters.

   3. It is usually a good idea to add a default constructor.

The finished code will look like this:

```
public class Tipos
{
    public int IdTipoPersona { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    public Tipos(int id, string descripcion)
    {
        IdTipoPersona = id;
        Descripcion = descripcion;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer...

Look, the web services returns a List of class "Tipos"

This class is defined in the web services like this:

public class Tipos{
      public string Descripcion;
      public int IdTipoPersona;
}

Comment: Wow....I have no clue how I missed that in the post, lol. I'll take a closer look.

Comment: Thanks for all!! But mi class is created in automatic when i add the reference to the web services

Comment: You could always add a go-between class that takes the objects of that class and puts it into objects of a new class that works with the combobox. It will ad a bit of extra overhead, but it would work.

Comment: Hello, i´m trying to add a new cgo-betweeb class, but it doesn´t work, can you help me please, this is the class:
   'public class PersonaTipo
    {
        public int Id_TipoPersona { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        public PersonaTipo(int Id_TipoPersona, string Descripcion) 
        {
            this.Id_TipoPersona = Id_TipoPersona;
            this.Descripcion = Descripcion;
        }
    }'

Answer (score 0):

I found the asnwer if someone needs it.

We need create a class intermediate class but we were working with entity framework, for this way, we need add the intermediate class like complex type in my model (entity framework).

And also we need override this class.

And it works so well.

Thanks for all @Goody